# Installing statsmodesl 0.7

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, statsmodels

I'd like to use statsmodels 0.7 and have tried `pip install statsmodels --upgrade`. However, only version 0.6.1 has been installed.

I guess the problem occurs because 0.7 is not still stable version.

Please let me know how to install statsmodels 0.7.

Comment: This is a development version. You need to pull the source and install - http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/install.html

Comment: @TomRon Thanks. I'll try installation from its source code.

Comment: The linked docs seem a little outdated. It can be done in one simple statement: `pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git`